# how to interpret regression equation with log transformed indpendent variable and some(not all) dependent variables are log transformed

Tags: linear-regression

how to interpret below linear regression equation
log(varaible0)=β0+β1×variable1+β2×log(variable2)+β3×variable3

I tried the same logic as the log-log model but it is giving me a wrong answer

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are fitting the log of variable0 in your model? Sometimes it is possible to use the exponent of one or more of the other variables, which would make interpretation of the fitting results more straightforward - this is the reason I ask.